# Understanding $\,\det(A+B)$

Tags: matrices, notation, determinant

From [this paper on Determinant of sums,](https://les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?3,file=30225,filename=Det_sum.pdf) where
\begin{equation}
\det(A+B) = \sum_{r} \sum_{\alpha,\beta} (-1)^{s(\alpha) + s(\beta)} \det(A[\alpha|\beta])\det(B[\alpha|\beta]),
\end{equation}
the meaning of $A[\alpha|\beta]$, and how the sum runs over $\alpha, \beta$ is not clear to me. Would appreciate an explanation of this this result.

Comment: Page $3$ (or page $131$) of your paper already explained what these symbols mean after display your posted equality (equality $(1)$ in the paper).

Comment: It talks of $\alpha, \beta$ being sequences! Could you illustrate it with an example, when say $n=4$?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are increasing sequences of length $r$: $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_r)$ and $\beta=(\beta_1,...,\beta_r)$, with $a_i$ and $\beta_i$ strictly increasing and drawn from the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Mark the rows $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r$ and the columns $\beta_1,...,\beta_r$ of $A$. Those rows and columns intersect at $r^2$ elements. The matrix formed by those elements is $A[\alpha|\beta]$. The matrix $B[\alpha|\beta]$ is similar, but using the rows that are not in $\alpha$ and the columns that are not in $\beta$.

Comment: For $n=4$, $r=2$, the sum over $\alpha, \beta$ is the sum over ordered pairs of $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)$, $30$ terms in total.

Comment: You mean, for $n=4$, we have $r=0,1,2,3,4$, and it is for $r=2$ we sum over the ordered pairs you mentioned? What about $r=0$ and $r=1$?

Comment: Note it should be $B(\alpha|\beta)$ (parentheses) to indicate the rejector minor, not $B[\alpha|\beta]$. You might find my [video](https://youtu.be/bb0nYuRABwc) helpful which explains a very similar formula for the determinant of a sum.